# Kotlin Multiplatform - Strategy sharing between iOS + Android

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

How are engineers utilizing kotlin multiplatform between iOS + Android?

We are adding a build-phase inside of the iOS project to compile the iOS build, do people have this pre-compiled for the main product app / separate from the repo?

Comment: It's up to you, you can build it each time(if kotlin part wasn't changed, the check only takes 1-2 sec) and store all the code inside one repo, or you can built the framework manually and share it to part of your team if they don't need to modify kotlin part

Answer (score 0):

I think this varies a lot across teams, generally speaking I'd approach it like this:

1. If you want gradual experimentation and in a more isolated way, a repository for shared code with dedicated team, that provides a binary (now XCFramework is possible with Kotlin/Native) can be a good option. The iOS team just pulls that in as an external lib.
2. The problem with the above is exactly isolation (harder to debug and read this shared code), if your goal is to overcome working in silos and include the iOS team more in the discussion I think cloning this shared code repo and using https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin to read & debug it is a nice lightweight approach to have this part of your code more open to iOS devs
3. If you want full contribution - iteration of read/write from iOS I'd go with a mono repo, full setup of the KMP ecosystem

Hopefully this covers your question at least in some perspective, let me know if you are interested in other aspects